# ZS-040 (HC-05) blueetooth module Arduino Mega

Tags: arduino-mega, bluetooth

I followed this tutorial http://www.martyncurrey.com/using-an-arduino-mega-with-a-hc-05-zs-040-at-mode/ and it seems that the AT mode is on. (the LED is blinking like it's supposed)

I connected my pins like this:

> BT VCC to Arduino 5V out. Disconnect before running the sketch
>
> BT GND to Arduino GND
>
> BT RX (through a voltage divider) to Arduino TX1 (pin 18)
>
> BT TX  to Arduino RX1 (no need voltage divider)   (pin 19)

This is the code I run: (from the tutorial)

```
// Basic Bluetooth test sketch 5a for the Arduino Mega. 
// AT mode using button switch
// HC-05 with EN pin and button switch
//
// Uses serial with the host computer and serial1 for communication with the Bluetooth module
//
//  Pins
//  BT VCC to Arduino 5V out. Disconnect before running the sketch
//  BT GND to Arduino GND
//  BT RX (through a voltage divider) to Arduino TX1 (pin 18)
//  BT TX  to Arduino RX1 (no need voltage divider)   (pin 19)
//
// When a command is entered in to the serial monitor on the computer 
// the Arduino will relay it to the Bluetooth module and display the result.
//

char serialByte = '0';
const byte  LEDPIN = 13; 

void setup() 
{
    pinMode(LEDPIN, OUTPUT);

    // communication with the host computer
    Serial.begin(9600);  

    Serial.println("Do not power the BT module");
    Serial.println(" ");
    Serial.println("On the BT module, press the button switch (keep pressed, and at the same time power the BT module");
    Serial.println("The LED on the BT module should now flash on/off every 2 seconds");
    Serial.println("Can now release the button switch on the BT module");
    Serial.println(" ");
    Serial.println("After entering AT mode, type 1 and hit send");
    Serial.println(" ");


    // wait for the user to type "1" in the serial monitor
    while (serialByte !='1')
    {
        if ( Serial1.available() )   {  serialByte = Serial1.read();  }
    }  


    // communication with the BT module on serial1
    Serial1.begin(38400);

    // LED to show we have started the serial channels
    digitalWrite(LEDPIN, HIGH);  

    Serial.println(" ");
    Serial.println("AT mode.");
    Serial.println("Remember to to set Both NL & CR in the serial monitor.");
    Serial.println("The HC-05 accepts commands in both upper case and lower case");
    Serial.println(" "); 
}


void loop() 
{
    // listen for communication from the BT module and then write it to the serial monitor
    if ( Serial1.available() )   {  Serial.write( Serial1.read() );  }

    // listen for user input and send it to the HC-05
   if ( Serial.available() )   {  Serial1.write( Serial.read() );  }
}
```

I want to mention that the baud rate is set to **9600** and **Both NL & CR** is also set.

The problem is when I insert `1` in the Serial Monitor and nothing happens. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

Connection:

- Bluetooth RXD to Arduino Mega pin 11
- Bluetooth TXD to Arduino Mega pin 10
- Bluetooth VCC to Arduino Mega 5V
- Bluetooth GND to Arduino Mega GND

I used this code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define RxD 10
#define TxD 11

SoftwareSerial BTSerial(RxD, TxD);

void setup(){
  // replace BAUDRATE as suggested
  BTSerial.begin(BAUDRATE);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  BTSerial.print("AT\r\n");
}

void loop(){

  if (BTSerial.available())
    Serial.write(BTSerial.read());

  if (Serial.available())
    BTSerial.write(Serial.read());

}
```

after setting AT mode as described in the tutorial above.

I tried running the code with `BAUDRATE` starting from 9600 to 460800:
[image]